# How was this equation for the hypotenuse of a triangle derived?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I've been staring at this for quite a while and simply can't understand how they got the equation for the hypotenuse. Probably has something to do with it being 5am my time!

[image]

I'm confused because (where z' is the hypotenuse):

$cos\theta_i = \frac{z}{z'}$

$sin\theta_i = \frac{x}{z'}$

Therefore:

$z'*cos\theta_i = z$

$z'*sin\theta_i = x$

So how do you go from those to the following?

$z' = x*sin\theta_i + z*cos\theta_i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really simple,

Draw a $\perp$ from Z to the hypotenous you will get two triangles then simply break the component of x and z on hypotenous and add them.

Component of z along z' is z $\cos(\theta_{1})$ and component of x along z' is z $\cos(90-\theta_{1})$=x $\sin(\theta_{1})$

so, z'= z $\cos(\theta_{1})$+x $\sin(\theta_{1})$

e.g.

Let $\theta_{1}$=60

[image]
in $\triangle$AEC

cos(B)=$\frac{AE}{x}$=$\cos(90-60)$= sin(60)

AE=xsin(60)

similarly, in $\triangle$BEC, $\frac{BE}{z}$=cos(60)$\Rightarrow$  BE=zcos(60)

therefore z'= BE+AE= xsin(60)+zcos(60)

since we assumed $\theta_{1}$=60

z'= z $\cos(\theta_{1})$+x $\sin(\theta_{1})$

Comment: You lost me there..

Comment: @DheerajKumar: (1) You should never, ever say to a student that something they don't understand is easy. (2) If it is as straightforward as you claim, then you admit the problem lies in your explanation. [As for the mathematics, you are correct; I have removed my answer. (but the last $z$ should be an $x$).]

Comment: I apologize....

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out your math (6am now, ha ha -- gotta love finals week!), but your final answer is different than the equation given in the figure.

Comment: @DheerajKumar: I accept. We all have to learn the hard way. Response to below: actually, a better image (one that does not look like a square and has the guidelines and appropriate lengths labelled) would probably be very helpful.

Comment: i can make it clear with an image taking $\theta$=60

Comment: in $\triangle$ BEC and AEC z and x are hypotenouse respectively

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute $x=z'\sin\theta$ and $z=z'\cos\theta$ into the formula you will get $z'=z'\sin^2\theta+z'\cos^2\theta$ which is a correct formula.

Comment: Ok, nice formula, but doesn't really answer my question. I'm just super confused how they obtained the formula shown in the figure.

Comment: @Nate, They obtained it by dropping a perpendicular from the point labeled "z" to the hypothenuse.  The base of the perpendicular splits the hypothenuse into a pair of intervals.  Their lengths are respectively $x\sin\theta$ and $z\cos\theta$ by definition of those trig functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let the point at which the horizontal dashed line at the top meets the vertical ($x$, in this case) axis be represented by $P$. Now drop a perpendicular to the slanted line ("the hypotenuse") from $P$. Let the intersection of that perpendicular with that line be called $Q$. Let the "red bullseye" (top-right corner) be $R$ and the origin (bottom-left "black bullseye") be $O$.

Now since $PR$ is parallel to the $z$-axis, it should be obvious that $\angle PRO = \theta_i$.

Consider right $\triangle PQR$. Its hypotenuse is $PR$. Which means that $QR = PR\cos \angle PRQ = z\cos \theta_i$.

Now consider right $\triangle PQO$. Its hypotenuse is $PO$. $\angle POQ = 90^{\circ} - \theta_i$. Also, $OQ = PO \cos \angle POQ = x \cos (90^{\circ} - \theta_i) = x\sin \theta_i$.

Finally, since $OR = OQ + QR$, the length you want is $x\sin \theta_i + z\cos \theta_i$